# image not store in database laravel

Tags: laravel, migration, store

I want to Create app in laravel that manage my events
i use this code for EventController

```
       public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([

              'inviter'=>'max:255',
              'date'=>'max:255',
              'phone'=>'max:255',
              'whatsapp'=>'max:255',
              'location'=>'max:255',
              'approval'=>'max:255',
              'number'=>'max:255',
              'description'=>'max:255',
              'track'=>'max:255',
        ]);
        $eve = new Event([
'inviter'=> $request->get('inviter'),
'date'=> $request->get('date'),
'phone'=> $request->get('phone'),
'whatsapp'=> $request->get('whatsapp'),
'location'=> $request->get('location'),
'number'=> $request->get('number'),
'approval'=> $request->get('approval'),
'description'=> $request->get('description'),
'track'=> $request->get('track'),
        ]);
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filePath = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->file->move(public_path('uploads/events'), $filePath);
            $eventImage = Image::createNew();
            $eventImage->filename_path = $filePath;
            $eventImage->original_filename = $fileName;
            $eventImage->event_id = $eve->id;
            $eventImage->save();
            }

     return redirect(route('event.index'))->with('success','Event Created');
}
```

but image dont create I think related to event_id when I was testing the code correctly and incorrectly

Comment: please check out you receive image object or not in controller. let me know

Comment: @HarshPatel The image is successfully uploaded and save data to database when I set a fixed value for the ID

Comment: you should to use `$eventObj = Event::create($request->all());` for insert or do `$eventObj = new Event();  $eventObj->name = $request->get('name'); $eventObj->save();  and then $eventId = $eventObj->id;` print out variable & check dd($eventId); let me known if any issue

Comment: you can also check https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_make `Make Method` for Create and return an un-saved model instance.

Comment: @HarshPatel save images data in database but each image get separated id in event!

Comment: sorry, but i doesn't understanding your problem. please edit your question & provider more details about your problem & as well as what is you wants to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$eve = Event::create([
'inviter'=> $request->get('inviter'),
'date'=> $request->get('date'),
'phone'=> $request->get('phone'),
'whatsapp'=> $request->get('whatsapp'),
'location'=> $request->get('location'),
'number'=> $request->get('number'),
'approval'=> $request->get('approval'),
'description'=> $request->get('description'),
'track'=> $request->get('track'),
        ]);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, Event save in Database but images not save

Comment: try dd($request->hasFile('file'), $eve->id)

Comment: Then the test answered false

191

Comment: this means request does not have any file therefore it is not inserting.